# Python using loop to update the cells in excel

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe is created with the `Join_Date` and `Name`

```
data = {'Join_Date': ['2023-01', '2023-01', '2023-02', '2023-03'],
        'Name': ['Tom', 'Amy', 'Peter', 'Nick']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have split the df by `Join_Date`, can it be printed into excel date by date by using for loop?

```
df_split = [df[df['Join_Date'] == i] for i in df['Join_Date'].unique()]
```

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ExcelWriter method in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

data = {'Join_Date': ['2023-01', '2023-01', '2023-02', '2023-03'],
        'Name': ['Tom', 'Amy', 'Peter', 'Nick']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_split = [df[df['Join_Date'] == i] for i in df['Join_Date'].unique()]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("example.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

skip_rows = 0
for df in df_split:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=2, startrow=2+skip_rows, index=False)
    skip_rows += df.shape[0]+2

writer.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas methods to do so, like this. (You can add a empty line if you really need it)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Join_Date': ['2023-01', '2023-01', '2023-02', '2023-03'],
        'Name': ['Tom', 'Amy', 'Peter', 'Nick']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def add_header(x):
    x.loc[-1] = 'Join_date', 'Name'
    return x.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

df_split = df.groupby(['Join_Date'], group_keys=False)

df_group = df_split.apply(add_header)

df_group.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

[image]

You can add the empty line editing the add_header func like:

```
def add_header(x):
    x.loc[-1] = ' ', ' '
    x = x.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
    x.loc[0.5] = 'Join_date', 'Name'
    x = x.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
    return x
```

[image]